# Jquery offset().top returns incorrect value on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, resize, offset

BLUF: On page resize, jQuery no longer returns the correct values for offset or position, causing scrolling to not function properly.

On page load and when the page is resized, this code is executed:

```
$.each(bodies,function(key,val){
    val.scroll = ($("#main"+val.id).position().top-layout.header.height);
});
```

I have also used offset:

```
$.each(bodies,function(key,val){
    val.scroll = ($("#main"+val.id).offset().top-layout.header.height);
});
```

After resizing the window, both offset and position return the wrong value.  However, when the page is resized when the page is scrolled all the way to the top, everything works again.

After calculating the scroll positions, elements are scrolled to using:

```
$("#viewport").animate({scrollTop:body.scroll},function(){
    $("#headerText").html(body.name);
});
```

It's worth noting that I'm using a fixed header at the top of the page

I've had this problem for weeks now and have scoured the web for solutions

Edit: Problem circumvented by calculating the desired scroll position instead of using offset or position.

Comment: You should get the top offset of the element again in resizing the window..! Like: `$(window).on('resize', function(){//code here to get the offset again});`

Comment: @RohitSharma The first block of code I included is executed whenever the window is resized.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Can you provide the live example of your problem, please..!

Comment: I am really unable to understand your problem, but I have made a codepen look [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/baXyZx). It may help.